# Expand existing PHP Message System

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat, message-system

### EDITED - nearly done! Please read --> "EDIT 1.1"

I implemented a very simple PHP / MYSQL based message system inside an app developer social plattform.
The structure of the messages table looks like this:

- message_id
- subject
- from_user_id
- from_user_name
- to_user_id
- has_read
- message_text
- message_timestamp

If you go to your personal message section you see your messages just sorted by message_timestamp. This is not a very good usability.

I want to refactor this, similar to whatsApp: As a user I want to navigate to my private message section and get an overview of all my chatpartners. When I Click on a chatpartner I expect to see our message history.

### 1.) I try to figure out how a perfekt table structure would look like for my new requirements, but I don't get a useful structure to:

1. show all users I am chatting with
2. show the messages rotatory when I click on a User
3. use very fast queries so my server is not overloaded with the message-system

---

### EDIT 1.1

Maybe I can change my table to this?

- **conversation_id** (NEW!)
- message_id
- subject
- from_user_id
- from_user_name
- to_user_id
- has_read
- message_text
- message_timestamp

And then when I click at a user, the conversation will be selected by (... WHERE 'conversation_id' = '123' ORDER BY 'message_id' ASC)

What do you think? **Is this to heavy for the database? Is there a better solution?**

Should i use nested Tables? What about the performance then?

---

2.)[answered -> "NO"] Is it better to store the messages in another Database separated from the other tables where I do the other stuff of my platform?

3.)[answered -> "Use Server-Sent Events"] How do I show a received message without reloading the page. Is there any Jquery-Ajax-PHP based Observer I can use?

Note: It's not a problem for me to use/build a chatsystem - but I want to be able to read the old messages every time I come back to the page and log myself in.

Comment: I don't think every message needs a `from_user_name`, since you can retrieve that information from the users table with `from_user_id`, but otherwise it looks like a decent table. I'm sure you're indexing it correctly. Using another database is only advantageous if that database is on another server. Updating a page without a complete reload is normally done with ajax, but you could use server-sent events if you want to be modern.

Comment: @user_name AngularJS is not a back-end technology framework.

Comment: @Jer I know that, I Quoted a comment that was "Many ways to do this: NodeJS, AngularJS and jQuery Ajax" - I did not write that. The user already deleted his comment so you can't read it anymore: NodeJS is a backend platform, Angular a javaScript Webframework, jQuery a js library and ajax is just a request method. I didn't understand what he was trying to tell me... :-)

Comment: @KIKO SOftware: Thanks, yes it is a descent table. Ok, so I will use the same Database because it is also the same server. Yes ajax is ok for displaying the new message but this is not my problem. I need an event to trigger the ajax call - i don't want to do this each second - maybe your "server sent event"s can help me here - i'll google it. EDIT: Oh this sounds like what I'am looking for. Does it need much ressources?